# How to show address in one row?

Tags: css

By using contact form 7 i created address page.

By selecting the city they can view the list of branches in that particular city but here i am getting small problem in first row address are not coming properly.

For reference please find the attached image and url
https://jasdental.in/dentist-near-me/
[image]

Thanks
SomuN

Comment: I think this is probably a CSS question. If you remove the `<br>`s between all your labels then this does go away - what did you intend the brs to do? - but I see slightly odd behaviour if I shrink the screen width, and at first glance I can't see why - fixed widths and font sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with your `<br>` between each label field. Its not a PHP problem its a CSS. Try to add

```
.wpcf7cf_group br {
   display: none;
}
```

to your css file or use a wordpress plugin like Simple Custom CSS.